# gcc optimization of code involving bit operations with constants

Tags: c, gcc

The code I'm maintaining has following types of lines at many places.

```
x = x | ((0x1 & 0x3ff) << 16);
x |= (0x7 << 28);
y = y | (0x3 << 8);
```

I compile the code with -O3 flag.
Does compiler (gcc) during optimization simplify and optimise the bit operations involving constants ?

e.g. On 1st line it should do

`x = x | 0x3ff0000;`

or on 3rd line it should do

`y = y | 0x300;`

instead of adding instructions to do the actual bit shift.

Comment: Yes, these constant expressions will be expanded at the precompiler stage. But `((0x1 & 0x3ff) << 16)` is `0x10000`, not `0x3ff0000`.

Comment: …and it will do so even without `-O3` or any `-O` fwiw.

Comment: Why don't you look at the assembly code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since all operands of the & and << operators in your expressions are integer constants, those sub-expressions are *integer constant expressions* and will get evaluated at compile-time.

Any half-decent compiler will replace those expressions with a hard-coded constant in the machine code, regardless of optimization level.